# Mensaje de una función

Tags: r

Quiero ver si en un df hay algún valor desconocido.

```
iris[1,1] <- NA

encu <- function(colum){
  
  if (anyNA(colum)) {
    
    cat("Hay un NA en",colum)
  }
  else {
    cat("No hay NA en", colum)
  }
}
```

Si pongo

```
encu(iris$Sepal.Length)
encu(iris$Petal.Width)
```

Sale mal. Lo que buco es que me diga

"Hay un NA en Sepal.Length"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que `cat` imprime toda la columna con la función ahorita. Hay que encontrar el nombre de la columna y usar eso con las declaraciones de imprimir.

Así funciona:

```
encu <- function(colum) {
  nombre <- deparse(substitute(colum))
  if(anyNA(colum)) {
    cat("Hay un NA en", nombre)
  }
  else {
    cat("No hay NA en", nombre)
  }
}
encu(iris$Sepal.Length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Genial, gracias.

Se podría añadir:

```
nombre <- gsub( ".*\\$", "", nombre )
```

Quedando finalmente:

```
encu <- function(colum) {

  nombre <- deparse(substitute(colum))
  nombre <- gsub( ".*\\$", "", nombre )

  if(anyNA(colum)) {
    cat("Hay un NA en", nombre)
  }
  else {
    cat("No hay NA en", nombre)
  }
}
encu(iris$Sepal.Length)
```